# Is every simple subquotient of a Jordan-Holder filtration isomorphic to a sub?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $0=M_0\subset M_1\dots\subset M_n=M$ be a Jordan Holder filtration of a finite $R$-module $M$. Is it true that for every $i$, there exist a submodule $N_i\subset M$ such that $N_i\cong M_i/M_{i-1}$?

(I think there should be counterexamples when $R$ is commutative. When $R$ is commutative, I think the claim is true as we know an finite module over $R$ is direct sum of module of artinian local rings.)

Answer (score 1):

This is not true for quiver algebras: for exmaple, take the quiver of the form: $1 \rightarrow 2$. Then $P(1)= K \rightarrow K$, and $0 \subseteq (0\rightarrow K) \subseteq (K \rightarrow K) $. Then $(K \rightarrow K)/(0 \rightarrow K) \cong (K \rightarrow 0)$, but there is no submodules of $K \rightarrow K$ that is isomorphic to $K \rightarrow 0$.(Here $K$ is a algebraically closed field under which the quiver algebra is defined)